# Error pygame has not attribute to blit

Tags: python, pygame

Tengo un problema, lo que sucede es que yo quería poner como fondo una imagen que le puse como nombre **`Paper.png`** y al hacerlo hice esto:

```
import pygame
import random
import hangman


paper = pygame.image.load("Paper.png")

words=['TABLE','ARMOR','DESIGN','PYGAME']
used=[]
guess=letters=""
pygame.init()
alphabet=pygame.image.load('alphabet.png')
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

#Question 2
i=random.randint(0,len(words)-1)
count=0
for x in range(len(words[i])):
  guess+='_ '
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
print(words[i])
run=True
while run:
  pygame.time.delay(100)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run=False
    #Question 3
    if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      l=hangman.keyboard(pos)
       if l!=None:
        guess,letters,used,count=hangman.valid(words[i],l,guess,letters,used,count)



  text1 = font.render(guess, True, black, white)
  textRect1 = text1.get_rect()
  textRect1.center = (300,100)

  text2 = font.render(letters, True, black, white)
  textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
  textRect2.center = (300,150)



  window.fill(white)

  pygame.blit(paper(0,0))
```

El code me sale bien sin el **`pygame.blit`** pero lo necesito para poner como fondo mi imagen no estoy segura de que esta mal porque me sale:

> error pygame has not attribute to blit

Entonces lo único que necesito es poner el paper de fondo en mmi juego, y eso es todo.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida Maria c:

Tu error se debe a un tema de concepto. El error es cierto, pygame no tiene el atributo blit.
Blit es un atributo de los objetos pygame.Surface. `pygame.display.set_mode` devuelve un pygame.Surface que representa lo dibujado en la ventana, por lo que si quieres dibujar en la ventana, tienes que hacer `window.blit(paper, (0,0))`.

Finalmente, hay que avisarle a Pygame que hiciste un cambio en la ventana con `pygame.display.flip`. En realidad, lo que hace este comando es actualizar la ventana.

**Tu código también tiene otros problemas de concepto, que enumeraré a continuación:**

- `window.fill(white)` es redundante si todo lo que dibujes será dibujado encima del fondo y tu fondo abarca toda la ventana. Si haces una pintura, ¿tiene sentido pintar todo de violeta para luego dibujarle encima un paisaje?¿No es mejor directamente pintar el paisaje?
- En ningún momento dibujas en la ventana los textos que creas. Blit acepta como segundo argumento tanto (x, y) como un pygame.Rect, del que obtiene la posición. Veremos esto aplicado más adelante en la respuesta.
  `font.render` devuelve un pygame.Surface que luego deberás dibujar en donde desees. En tu caso, supongo que quieres que el texto aparezca en la ventana.

Con todos estos consejos aplicados, el código donde intentas dibujar tu fondo y los textos quedaría así:

```
text1 = font.render(guess, True, black, white)
textRect1 = text1.get_rect()
textRect1.center = (300,100)

text2 = font.render(letters, True, black, white)
textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
textRect2.center = (300,150)

# Notese que dibujo los textos luego de dibujar el papel, ya que si no, los textos se dibujan pero tu fondo los cubre y no se verían en pantalla.
window.blit(paper, (0,0))
window.blit(text1, textRect1)
window.blit(text2, textRect2)

#Le pido a Pygame que actualice la ventana
pygame.display.flip()
```

Te recomiendo echarle una mirada a la documentación oficial de Pygame para entender mejor como funciona. Aquí te dejo el link: https://www.pygame.org/docs/